# Histogram Equalization of 1d values and reverse transform in python

Tags: python, curve-fitting

I have a set of 1D values. When I plot the histogram of the values, I notice that they're not uniformly distributed. Can I find a non-linear mapping, such that the transformed scores are uniformly distributed? I also need the reverse transform function as well.

One way I know is to do histogram equalization like in images. Is there any inbuilt function in python to achieve this?

Comment: If you use openCV you can use `cv.equalizeHist`

Comment: That's for images right? I need for 1D data and I need the inverse transform function as well, meaning to convert equalized values back to original distribution.